# Allow user with admin role to consume all apis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I configured my API security side using spring security :

```
 http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests(authRequests -> {
                        // Allow all resource to admin
                        authRequests.antMatchers("*").hasRole(RoleType.Fields.ADMIN);
                        // Permissions OPTIONS
                        authRequests.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();
                        // Management endpoints
                        authRequests.mvcMatchers("/management/**", "/docs/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll();
                        // Business APIs
                        authRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    });
            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
```

for other roles, I created a filter to get authoritie, it works fine, the problem is that I want to give the **ROLE_ADMIN** access to all resource, when I used `antMatchers("*")` , the api gives 403 code.

Comment: can you try "/*" put slash

Comment: @abidinberkay I did but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `csrf` protection:

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

and use `anyRequest()` instead of `antMatchers("*")`:

```
authRequests.anyRequest().hasRole(RoleType.Fields.ADMIN)
```

Comment: it did not solve the problem, to consume the api I need to add ROLE_ADMIN at ```@RolesAllowed```, thing that I try to avoid, I want to give the admin all the rights to consume apis